# Laravel Voyager overwrite BREAD controller

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I've started to use Voyager and I've problems with a controller.

I've create a new table in database called Progress, voyager by default create a BREAD form to browse read delete and add items .

I like to put a default value into a field when the user go to add a new item. The default value that I like to put is authentication user_id

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to override the package views? I've never used voyager so I'm just taking a shot in the dark here, but if you can publish the vendor files and modify them you can set the default that way.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that completely outside of Voyager.

First exclude the `authentication_user_id` from the Add form (in Voyager's database interface). If the field doesn't take a null value you can set some temporary default, or modify your migrations - whichever is most convenient.

Next create a [model observer](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#model-observers) and then utilise the `created()` function. For example:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Observers;

    use App\Models\Project;

    class ProgressObserver
    {
        /**
         * Listen to the Progress created event.
         *
         * @param  Progress  $progress
         * @return void
         */
         public function created(Progress $progress)
         {
            $progress->authentication_user_id = WHATEVER_YOU_DO_HERE;
            $progress->save();
         }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by creating a model for your bread, as shown in image
[image]

after you have done creating a model for your bread you can create a function named `save`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use TCG\Voyager\Traits\Translatable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Auth;

class MyViewModel extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = "my_view";

    public function save(array $options = [])
    {
        $this->user_id = \Auth::user()->id;
        parent::save();
    }
}
```

now whenever you save any record in administration of voyager, you will see current login user id is getting saved in your database table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a migration to write a default value for that field

Answer (score 0):

You have to add following code into the model like this,

```
//assign created_by loggedin user
 public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    $this->creating([$this, 'onCreating']);
    parent::__construct($attributes);
}

public function onCreating($row)
{
    // Placeholder for catching any exceptions
    if (!\Auth::user()->id) {
        return false;
    }

    $row->setAttribute('created_by', \Auth::user()->id);
    $row->setAttribute('assign_to', \Auth::user()->id);
}
```

i have adding this because of my project need this. you can also add your field in onCreating() function.